# how to stop sites setting service-workers, without blocking cookies, in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, services, cookies, daemon

I want to be able to block service-workers from being allowed by default, on google chrome. But I want to allow cookies by default. I dont see a way of blocking service-workers without blocking all cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Since a service-worker is JavaScript, you can try to install any extension that will block JS unless you expressly authorize it to run on any given page or domain.

I use NoScript Suite on both Chrome (Slimjet for me) and Firefox, and it does ease the strain on my PC.